# Kotlin - Mongo DB - aggerate query not returning sum as expected

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, kotlin, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

im trying to read the sum of a certain fields from Mongo DB using Kotlin and Mongo-spring-data.

```
val agg = Aggregation.newAggregation(
            Aggregation.match(Criteria().and("metadata.expectedTurnover").ne(null)),
            Aggregation.group().sum("metadata.expectedTurnover").`as`("total")
    )

val result: List<PresaleTurnoverCount> = mongoTemplate.aggregate(agg, PresaleQuery::class.java, PresaleTurnoverCount::class.java).mappedResults
```

This is the expected model for data.

```
    @Document("presale")
    data class PresaleTurnoverCount(
        @Id
        @JsonProperty("_id")
        var mongoId: String? = null,
        var total: BigDecimal? = null
)
```

Sample data

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"60e297cdc86f9502c6c89c41"},"id":"1fc7bbea-56d5-429f-bac1-277f87000b60","metadata":{"createdTs":{"$date":"2021-07-05T05:25:33.599Z"},"personName":"Oldest intekas","modifiedBy":"CRM","expectedTurnover": "10", "processState":{"employeeComments":[]}}
```

And the output:

[image]

Comment: Can you post some sample data, please?

Comment: @Valijon Added a sample datum.

Answer (score 0):

After a while i started aggregating data in compass mongo db.
It never worked then i realised my fields were saved as a string

```
expectedTurnover": "10",
```

As soon as i changed that in compass numeric value it started working.
Now i've got to figure out how to save data as BigDecimal and not as string.

[image]

Comment: Current solution was to change from BigDecimal to Long value.